# Position 2 buttons bottom right with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to layout 2 buttons bottom right within an area. (yes/no).

- I found out I can use pull-right for the buttons to stack them right.
- I've also found that:

`position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;`

will push them down.
Unfortunately when I use absolute positioning the pull-right is out of effect, I suppose they are not compatible.

How can I position 2 buttons to bottom right within an area using bootstrap?

```
<div>
    Hello, here is the question
</div>
<div style ="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">Yes</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `right:0;`.

```
<div>
    Hello, here is the question
</div>
<div style ="position: absolute; bottom: 0;right:0;">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Yes</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sjOr0SOU4u)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `position:absolute`, you can use this instead of `float:right;`

```
right:0px;
```